# Ping Multiple PowerShell

Tags: script, powershell

estoy queriedo hacer un script en powershell para realizar ping a multiples direciones ip. El problema esta cuando hago el `ping - t [direccionIp]` y apreto `CTRL+C` para finalizar el proceso y que muestre los resultados de paquetes enviados y perdidos, ya que al hacerlo powershell mata el proceso.

Alquien tiene una idea de como hacerlo?

En la imagen puede verse el codigo y como al apretar CTRL+C se cierra la ejecucion del script:

[image: Captura de la ejecucion]

Comment: Con el parámetro -n puedes indicar el número de intentos de ping, en lugar de pedir infinitos y cancelar con ctrl+c. Por ejemplo ping -n 3 192.168.1.1 hace 3 intentos y se cancela automáticamente

Comment: No me sirve, ya que tengo que permitir al usuario que corte el envio de pings

Answer (score 1):

no se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. Pero te quiero aclarar algunas cosas de como esta armado tu script.

1. Nunca va a hacer ping a "NumeroIP2" o los que sigan.
2. El resultado del ping no lo guardas en ninguna variable, por lo que no se va a poder manipular.
3. Existe el comando PathPing que te da muy estadísticas.

Aun así te para seguir masomenos tu ejemplo te recomiendo que en lugar de ping uses el cmdLet "Test-Connection".

```
$serverName = "127.0.0.1", "8.8.8.8","lalala"
$noResponde = 0

while($True) {
    foreach ($server in $serverName){
    $respuesta= Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($respuesta -ne "true")
        {
            write-host ($noResponde++) #Acá podes ver la cantidad que no respondió
            write-host "No responde el server" $server #| Out-File -FilePath c:\carpeta\noresponden.txt
        }      
    }
}
```

Con "| Out-File -FilePath" podes redirigir la salida del comando.
Podes hacer lo mismo para los que responden, modificar el tamaño del paquete, el timeout, etc, a todo lo podes evaluar.

Para hacer saber mas del cmdLet Test-Connection, podes dirigirte su [documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Test-Connection?view=powershell-5.0)
En mi ejemplo lleva el -Quiet para que devuelva solo verdadero o falso, pero deberías evaluar cual es la mejor manera de implementarlo en tu caso.

Para tener mas información también podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Test-Connection -Quiet 8.8.8.8 | Get-Member
```

Lo que te da mas información de como usarlo.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una solucion que a mi me funciona

```
***###La función Test-Connction podes utilizarla para hacer ping a multiples computadoras####***
Test-Connection -ComputerName test1,test2,test3 -Count 3 -Delay 2 -MaxHops 255 -BufferSize 256
```

Es sencillo y me funciona para lo que necesito.
Saludos.